# ggplotly with long names in the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have data with long names which i would like to plot using `ggplotly`.

That's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
temp<-data.frame(x=c("longgggggggggggggggggggggggg_nameeeeeeeeeeeeeee1", "longggggggggggggggggggggggggg_nameeeeeeeeeeeeeee2"),
                 y=c(5,10))

break_str<-function(str,n){
  if(nchar(str)<=n)
    return(str)
  ans<-""
  for(i in 1:ceiling(nchar(str)/n)){
    if(i<ceiling(nchar(str)/n)){
      ans<-paste0(ans,substr(str,start=((i-1)*n+1),stop=min(i*n,nchar(str))),"\n")
    } else{
      ans<-paste0(ans,substr(str,start=((i-1)*n+1),stop=min(i*n,nchar(str))))
    }
  }
  return(ans)
}

p <- ggplot(temp, aes(x=x, y=y)) +  
  labs(x="x",y="y") + geom_bar(stat="identity") +  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) lapply(x,function(str){break_str(str,10)})) 

ggplotly(p)
```

As you can see I use a custom `break_str` function which works similar to `stringr::str_wrap` but still it doesn't remove the margin in the plot.

This problem doesn't show up when in the `ggplot` version of `p`.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you stumbled over a bug in `ggplotly` (maybe you should raise an issue on [github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly)). I had a look into the source code. The issue is that `ggplotly` does not take linebreaks in the tick labels into account when computing the margins. Hence, the margin is set too wide. This problem does not arise if you make the plot using `plotly`. However, as a simple workaround you can force `automargin` to do its job by adding the layout option `margin = list(l = 0)` like so:

```
ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(
    margin = list(l = 0)
  )
```

which results in this plot:

[image]